# Get an image in parent folder from react code

Tags: css, reactjs, image, path

I want to make a background image of a div.
I use an image in the parent folder of my file, but when I want to access it with a function, it doesn't work:

```
test() {
  return '../test.png'
}

render() {
  return (
    <div
      style={{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + require( this.test() ) + ')' }}
    >
    </div>
  )
}
```

Note that it works when I define the background image in the CSS file (which is in the same position) or when I do this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div
      style={{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + require( '../test.png' ) + ')'}}
    >   
    </div>
   )
 }
```

It works also when I place the image in the same folder as the code and when I do this:

```
test() {
  return './test.png'
}

render() {
  return (
    <div
      style={{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + require( this.test() ) + ')' }}
    >
    </div>
   )
 }
```

If you have any idea, share it! Thank you.

Comment: Webpack doesn't know what the value of `this.test()` will be, so it can't require it at build time. What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to dynamically require an image from a variable?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I want  to dynamically display div with background image

Comment: Webpack might be able to handle \`../${this.test()}.png\` if you just return `'test'` from `this.test()`.

Comment: Thank but do you think it's possible with a native react ? And it's strange, I already did this manipulation, it worked.

Comment: I don't know exactly how it works to be honest, but I think it has to be able to say in which directory you will import the image from. If you just have any variable, it could be from any directory. If you write \ `../${someVarible}.png\`, it will know which files to include in your build that you might choose from.

Comment: I see what you want to say, but I found an other way to do it without webpack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently it's a story of time: the jsx hasn't the time to get the image from a function.
To solve my problem, I just returned the all css object:

```
test() {
  let test = 'test'
  return { backgroundImage: 'url(' + require( '../' + test + '.png' ) + ')' }
}

render() {
  return (
    <div
      style={ this.test() }
    >
    </div>
   )
 }
```